# uninstalling a parental control software Homeguard

Tags: uninstall, parental-controls

I installed a software named Homeguard Pro ( Veridium). But I cannot uninstall it now because the option does not show up and it's kind of working in disguise. I checked almost all the methods using third party softwares and registry method.
When I check the program files folder where it is installed there is no installer or uninstaller.

However, on the official website it is mentioned that we can uninstall it by going to the folder and double clicking uninstall.exe.

I am so much in problem. I have McAfee Live in my system. I doubt that antivirus has deleted files of this program. Kindly help.

Comment: What happens exactly when you run the uninstaller?  Please [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: Download the installer from the Company website and run it, either it will give you an option to uninstall it, or installing it should add a proper uninstall option.

Comment: @Mokubai...it says the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: @ramhound...I edited the question. There is no uninstaller in the system. It's working in disguise.Program files/ Homeguard : This folder has no uninstaller. It is also not present in remove programs.

Comment: If `Homeguard Pro` does not appear in Add/Remove Program be sure you are attempting to uninstall it with the same user that initially installed.  Outside of that you should simply reinstall it, using that same user, then uninstall it.

Answer (score -1):

You can try Method 6 from the link below. I wouldn't use Method 7 since the software might not be secure.

http://www.uninstallhelps.com/how-to-uninstall-homeguard.html#Method6

My other suggestion is to use CCleaner. I know you have mentioned you already tried third party tools but,not sure if you have used CCleaner.

Here is the link for CCleaner
https://www.ccleaner.com/

Comment: @SudhirSharma You might have to contact their support if it's that persistent  support@veridium.net

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.